# Unable to found feed input Error while predicting on Re-trained Inception-V3 in Tensorflow

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm currently trying to make predictions on **re-trained Inception-V3** model in TensorFlow. 
When I'm trying to run inference on image with

`bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image \
    --graph=/path/output_graph.pb --labels=/path/output_labels.txt \
    --output_layer=final_result \
    --image=/path/to/test/image`

I'm getting an error
`E tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:303] Running model failed: Not found: FeedInputs: unable to find feed output Mul`

I used transfer learning to fine tune Inception trained on Imagenet dataset, to train on my own 1000+ classes. Training & evaluation processes were ok. I exported graph with `tf.train.write_graph()` and freeze it with https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py

Did anyone faced this problem??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the graph you are using, the feed or "input_layer" node has been renamed and is no longer called "Mul". You need to find the name of the node where inputs should be injected into your saved graph, and pass the node name via the --input_layer flag.

The easiest way to find the node name is just to make sure to set it explicitly to something you know when you build the graph in the first place.